# Leica Geo Office Cannot Process Data?

Tags: gps, leica-geo-office

I have imported base and rover data to Leica Geo Office and did a selection to the reference and rover station in the GPS-Processing Tab.

Why are the Process button and Data Processing parameters still inactive?

[image]